# Cannot import shared library with g++

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, g++, shared-libraries

i made a shared library, linked it to a main program, but this main program cannot see any of the shared library methods, nor import it's headers. 
This is what i did:

1. I compiled each cpp file of the library in position independent code

> ```
> g++ -c -fPIC -o objname.o objname.cpp -I"HeadersFolder"
> ```

2. I created the shader library, and it is correctly created with the
   right name in my main directory

> ```
> g++ -shared -o libmylib.so obj1.o obj2.o etc.. etc..
> ```

3. I'm trying to compile a simple main with:

> ```
> g++ main.cpp -L. -lmylib
> ```

Now in this  main i imported one of the lib headers, something like:

```
#include <Header.hpp>
```

And g++ tells me no such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Now in this main i imported one of the lib headers, something like: ..."*

You also need to add the `-I` option to compile `main.cpp` in this case:

```
g++ main.cpp -I"HeadersFolder" -L. -lmylib
```

Also you should use

```
#include "Header.hpp" // Note the quotes "
```

the angle brackets (`<>`) are for including system headers (that could possibly collide with your own when the preprocessor evaluates them).

Comment: Damn thanks, works perfectly!
I thought the headers would be somehow included in the compiled library, i didn't think you must have them anyway

Comment: @user3578051 If you `#include` them in `main.cpp`, you need this to make them accessible for the preprocessor. The MSVC compiler provides an `#import` preprocessor directive that automatically resolves this. Maybe hence your confusion comes from.